# Проверка победителя в крестиках-ноликах на поле NxN,где количество необходимых знаков для победы задается пользователем

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Пытаюсь реализовать выбор победителя,но получается только для поля три на три.

```
`//функция поиска победы по диагонали
  bool checkdiaog(char sym)//sym-символ либо игрока либо компьютера('X','0')
    {
        int t = 0;
        int r = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < stroka; k++)//Stroka -кол-во строк в нашей матрице
        {
            if (massiv[k][k] == sym)//проверка победы по главной диагонали
            {
                t++;//счетчик входов в if
            }
            if (massiv[stroka - k - 1][k] == sym)//проверка победы по побочной диагонали
            {
                r++;//счетчик входов в if
            }
        }
        if (t == kol1)//kol1-кол-во крестиков или ноликов необходимых для победы
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (r == kol1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //проверка победы по горизонтали и вертикали
    bool checkLine(char sym)//sym-символ либо игрока либо 
    компьютера('X','0')
    {
        int t;
        int r;
        for (int k = 0; k < stroka; k++)//stroka - кол-во строк в нашем двумерном массиве
        {
            t = 0;
            r = 0;
            for (int s = 0; s < stolb; s++)//stolb-кол-во столбцов в нашем двумерном массиве
            {
                //проверка горизонтали
                if (massiv[k][s] == sym)//massiv-это двумерный массив(char) в котором хранятся все шаги игрока('X') и компьютера('0') до текущего момента
                {
                    t++;
                    if (t == kol1)//кол-во крестиков или ноликов необходимых для победы
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                //проверка вертикали
                if (massiv[s][k] == sym)
                {
                    r++;
                    if (r == kol1)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }`
```

Если поможете найти более эффективный алгоритм поиска ,то буду  вам безумно благодарен.

Comment: Вы предлагаете читателям самим угадывать, какая переменная что значит? Где тут `N`? Где тут "поле NxN"? Где тут "количество необходимых знаков"? В чем назначение этих двух функций?

Comment: Да,вы правы. Я добавил коментарии в коде.

Comment: В коде нет числа 3, поэтому он или работает доя любого размера, и не работает для поля 3х3 тоже.

Comment: Это только проверка на победу,полный код находится по ссылке https://github.com/vanserov/tic-tac-toe-game. Пользователь вводит в main кол-во столбцов(stolb),строк(stroka) и кол-во знаков необходимых для победы(kol1). Я проверял на где эти три переменные равны тройкам и у меня вроде работало.